# Change search to outpout category name instead of Post type name

Tags: ajax, search

Im using a ajax search which is great, however i would like to change it to show custom post type categorys instead of custom post type. I added the taxonomy for the custom post type categorys, and works great, but te titel is still "portfolio" which is the CPT, and i want the titels to be the categorys. The code:

```
if (!function_exists('sf_ajaxsearch')) {
    function sf_ajaxsearch() {
        $search_term = trim($_POST['s']);
        $search_query_args = array(
            's' => $search_term,
            'post_type' => 'any',
             'portfolio-category' => 'fullvids',             
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => false,
            'numberposts' => -1
        );
        $search_query_args = http_build_query($search_query_args);
        $search_results = get_posts( $search_query_args );
        $count = count($search_results);
        $shown_results = 5;

        $search_results_ouput = "";

        if (!empty($search_results)) {

            $sorted_posts = $post_type = array();

            foreach ($search_results as $search_result) {
                $sorted_posts[$search_result->post_type][] = $search_result;
                // Check we don't already have this post type in the post_type array
                if (empty($post_type[$search_result->post_type])) {
                    // Add the post type object to the post_type array
                    $post_type[$search_result->post_type] = get_post_type_object($search_result->post_type);
                }           
            }

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($sorted_posts as $key => $type) {
                $search_results_ouput .= '<div class="search-result-pt">';
                if(isset($post_type[$key]->labels->name)) {
                    $search_results_ouput .= "<h6>".$post_type[$key]->labels->name."</h6>";
                } else if(isset($key)) {
                    $search_results_ouput .= "<h6>".$key."</h6>";
                } else {
                    $search_results_ouput .= "<h6>".__("Other", "swiftframework")."</h6>";                  
                }

                foreach ($type as $post) {

                    $img_icon = "";

                    $post_format = get_post_format($post->ID);
                    if ( $post_format == "" ) {
                        $post_format = 'standard';
                    }
                    $post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);

                    if ($post_type == "post") {
                        if ($post_format == "quote" || $post_format == "status") {
                            $img_icon = "fa-quote-left";
                        } else if ($post_format == "image") {
                            $img_icon = "fa-picture-o";
                        } else if ($post_format == "chat") {
                            $img_icon = "fa-comments-o";
                        } else if ($post_format == "audio") {
                            $img_icon = "fa-music";
                        } else if ($post_format == "video") {
                            $img_icon = "fa-film";
                        } else if ($post_format == "link") {
                            $img_icon = "fa-link";
                        } else {
                            $img_icon = "fa-pencil";
                        }
                    } else if ($post_type == "product") {
                        $img_icon = "fa-shopping-cart";
                    } else if ($post_type == "portfolio") {
                        $img_icon = "fa-picture-o";
                    } else if ($post_type == "team") {
                        $img_icon = "fa-user";
                    } else if ($post_type == "galleries") {
                        $img_icon = "fa-picture-o";
                    } else {
                        $img_icon = "fa-file";
                    }

                    $post_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
                    $post_permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);

                    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' );

                    $search_results_ouput .= '<div class="search-result">';

                    if ($image) {
                        $search_results_ouput .= '<div class="search-item-img"><a href="'.$post_permalink.'">'.$image.'</div>';
                    } else {
                        $search_results_ouput .= '<div class="search-item-img"><a href="'.$post_permalink.'" class="img-holder"><i class="'.$img_icon.'"></i></a></div>';
                    }

                    $search_results_ouput .= '<div class="search-item-content">';
                    $search_results_ouput .= '<h5><a href="'.$post_permalink.'">'.$post_title.'</a></h5>';
                    $search_results_ouput .= '</div>';

                    $search_results_ouput .= '</div>';

                    $i++;
                    if ($i == $shown_results) break;
                }

               $search_results_ouput .= '</div>';
                if ($i == $shown_results) break;
            }

            if ($count > 1) {
                $search_results_ouput .= '<a href="'.get_search_link($search_term).'" class="all-results">'.sprintf(__("View all %d results", "swiftframework"), $count).'</a>';
            }

        } else {

            $search_results_ouput .= '<div class="no-search-results">';
            $search_results_ouput .= '<h6>'.__("No results", "swiftframework").'</h6>';
            $search_results_ouput .= '<p>'.__("No search results could be found, please try another query.", "swiftframework").'</p>';
            $search_results_ouput .= '</div>';

        }

        echo $search_results_ouput;
        die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_sf_ajaxsearch', 'sf_ajaxsearch');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sf_ajaxsearch', 'sf_ajaxsearch');    
}

if (!function_exists('sf_ajaxurl')) {
    function sf_ajaxurl() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
    add_action('wp_head','sf_ajaxurl');
}
?>
```

Comment: plugin specific questions are better asked at the plugin support channels, here such questions are off-topic.

Comment: Im not using a plugin.. My theme has this built in.